# Button for each click calls function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my html structure. Every `li` has `height:100vh;`

```
<button class="giu"></button>
<ul>
  <li class="product" id="product1"></li>
  <li class="product" id="product2"></li>
  <li class="product" id="product3"></li>
  <li class="product" id="product4"></li>
</ul>
```

When I click the button I want the page to scroll down to the next `li`

I found this jquery code (by user Vohuman), but it works only the first time.

```
$('.giu').click(function(event) {
    // Preventing default action of the event
    event.preventDefault();
    // Getting the height of the document
    var n = $(window).height();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: n }, 1000);
//                                       |    |
//                                       |    --- duration (milliseconds) 
//                                       ---- distance from the top
});
```

I'm not a javascript/jquery expert, can you explain why is it wrong?

Comment: If you don't change the point to scroll to on every click, it will always go to the same place in the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you are not far off from the answer you are seeking but at the same time you are missing the most critical component. In order to achieve the scrollable action with your button, you must do the following:

1. Capture the top position of the first element in the unordered list.
2. Animate the entire document (html or body for that matter), to move it's top position to the current unordered list element you are working with, which to start will be the first one.
3. Keep a count of the number of elements you are going through, so that when you hit the last element in your list, your counter acts as a flag to the system to indicate which element to reference to next.
4. Added functionality (totally optional ...why not) for the win! Let's make it so that when you hit the last element, clicking on the button will take you back up the list. I hope it inspires you to use it in different implementations.

HTML

```
<button class="giu">Click to go to next</button>
<ul class="products">
    <li class="product" id="product1"></li>
    <li class="product" id="product2"></li>
    <li class="product" id="product3"></li>
    <li class="product" id="product4"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS, I added this so it's very crystal clear when you see the below jsFiddle. It is also relevant to the jQuery implementation I used. If you're confused with how CSS is helping here, make sure to look at [n-th child selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

```
.product {
    height: 100vh;
}
ul :nth-child(1) {
    background-color: blue;
}
ul :nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
ul :nth-child(3) {
    background-color: green;
}
ul :nth-child(4) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // grabbing the total number of list elements (product) under the unordered list (products)
    var count_li = $('.products .product').length;
    // of course, let's make sure we have any elements before we do anything
    if(count_li){
        // counts the current element we are looking at, beginning with the first (1) one.
        var count = 1;
        $('.giu').click(function(event) {
            // we want to animate the whole document to move
            $("html, body").animate({
                // we are moving the document to the 'top' of the desired element, in this case the n-th list element
                scrollTop: $(".products :nth-child(" + count + ")").offset().top + "px"
            }, 500); // a 0.5 sec delay for visual smoothness
            ++count;
            // this here is 'extra' because I thought it would be nice to loop back to the beginning, giving the button an endless functionality.
            if(count > count_li){
                count = 1;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a live example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/jsboy51r/)

Enjoy! feel free to comment if you need anything else.

Comment: Thank you, very detailed!
But what if I want to skip a li and go, for example, to 1 then 3 etc. ?
Another question: my first li has a ::before element, does it count as child too?

Comment: you should not have to worry about the ::before, since it is a) a pseudo class, and b) it is not an element, rather a type of selector. In short, it does not count as a child. Feel free to look at how ::before behaves here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Comment: @axiedrella23 if this answer helped you the most and is acceptable to you, then make sure to "accept" it. it helps everyone else who comes to see your question in the future. Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollTop with **offset().top** to scroll it to LI node.

**HTML**

Do add a "active" class on LI item which you want to show at first on page load. For me, it's the first LI item.

```
<button class="giu">Animate To Next avaiable List Item</button>
<ul>
  <li class="product active" id="product1">1</li>
  <li class="product" id="product2">2</li>
  <li class="product" id="product3">3</li>
  <li class="product" id="product4">4</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.giu').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var n = $(window).height();
    $('li.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".product.active").offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

**Fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/fhg1g974/

Comment: he want to animate to the next li , this must have an count of li and then to animate to the next LI index stocked in a variable :)

Comment: to cater this scenario, i have added active class on first LI by default (on page load)

Comment: but if you are in the fourth element , this not find the next() li :) you must just add an condition if this active item is equal to the length of li then we must find the first() li and then add the active class :)

Comment: yes, if only we want the scroll with cyclic behavior. Looking at the current trends of single page scroll, it doesn't seem like an option where you want page to be cyclic rotate rather we can put "TOP" link on bottom.

Comment: you can create a jsFiddle account, make a fiddle there, save it and update it as needed thus creating various versions of your code. You can use 'set as base' to make the version you're happy with the base of your fiddle and share that, rather than update it by hand here on Stack Overflow. I hope it helps

Comment: Can you tell me how to go back to the top when I'm at the end of the ul, within this code?

Comment: @AGE thanks a lot buddy. You gave a right direction which will save lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

you need global variable for pointing what is the current view and jump to the next is you can or return for the beginning for example:

HTML

```
<button onclick="makeClick()" />

<ul>
  <li class="product" id="product1"></li>
  <li class="product" id="product2"></li>
  <li class="product" id="product3"></li>
  <li class="product" id="product4"></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var currentLocation = 'product1'
function makeClick()
{
  if(currentLocation  == 'product1')
  {
    //go to next element
    currentLocation = 'product2';
  }
  else if(currentLocation  == 'product2')
  {
     //go to the first element if reach to end
     currentLocation = 'product1'
  }

   $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + currentLocation).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```